# Add ontimeupdate="timeUpdate()" into video tag using jQPlayer

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I am struggling with the problem of adding `ontimeupdate="timeUpdate()"` into video tag (HTML5).
I am using [jQPlayer](https://github.com/vebersol/jQPlayer) which is HTML5 Video Player Plugin for jQuery.
I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It's better to use a code style for wrting a code in posts, also inster the hyperlink into the text instead of address. I've edited for you.

Comment: surely you are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

Following jQPlayer's demo, you can use something like this:

```
var videoElement = $('#video-element'),
    options = {}, // your options
    playerTest = videoElement.jQPlayer(options);

videoElement.find('video').bind('timeupdate', function () {
    console.log('timeupdate', this.currentTime);
});
```

Comment: Can you please comment it more?

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't seem to fulfill the same role as ontimeupdate="timeUpdate()" that I had included in the video tag.